# How to fix Material-UI Select w/ MenuItem where MenuItem being rendered horizontally?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I've been playing with Material-UI with React/Next.js and I'm running across a weird and persistent bug. I can't get the `<Select>` to render a regular vertical dropdown menu. How do I get the `<MenuItem>`s to render vertically?

I searched the docs and can't find anything. It's also worth noting my code is pretty much the same as the example:

```
render (
    <div>
        <FormControl
            fullWidth
            style={{
            paddingBottom: formError
                ? `${paddingBeneathFormControls}px`
                : `${paddingBeneathFormControls + 22}px`,
            }}
        >
            <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Age</InputLabel>
            <Select
            className="test"
            labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
            label="Age"
            value={10}
            >
            <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
            </Select>
            {formError && (
            <FormHelperText error>
                Please enter a valid value.
            </FormHelperText>
            )}
        </FormControl>
    </div>
)
```

[image: Output Screenshot]

Comment: If you remove the extra styling on `FormControl`, does that make a difference?

Comment: The dropdown list is rendered using the `ul` and `li` tags. Do you have some global css somewhere that is affecting how `ul` and `li` tags are styled? Maybe to format a horizontal navbar or something?

Comment: @smac89 - great point but unfortunately it didn't help. Still renders horizontally.

Comment: @ShawnFlahave This is also a great point but no code is touching `ui` or `li`...

Answer (score 5):

There may be some unexpected side-effects for others, but I found a solution to my problem. I was using `@mui/material` library, which I figured was the more modern version - they say NASA, Netflix, Spotify and others use this library. I simply changed my import to `@material-ui/core`, which exposes the same elements I was using (`Select`, `MenuItem`, `FormControl`, `FormHelperText`, `InputLabel`, `TextField`). I'm not entirely sure where these two libraries differ but in my case simply switching that made all my code work.

It's worth noting that using both adds some conflicting styling behavior - I tried at first to only borrow the `Select` and `MenuItem` components from `@material-ui/core`, but when I imported that library it broke the component styling for `@mui/material` components.

Comment: `@mui/material` is the namespace used for mui v5, `@material-ui/core` is what was used prior to that. It seems that you either didn't properly include mui v5 and all its [dependencies](https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4/#update-mui-version), or you were actually using an earlier version of the library. See the [migration guide](https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4/) to learn how to migrate to v5. Also make sure you are following the proper [guide](https://mui.com/guides/minimizing-bundle-size/) on importing components from the library, or are using one of the options available